# inconsistent behavior of entityManager persistence with field type bigDecimal

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby, bigdecimal

I use the entity manager to save data for several types like int byte string double etc and this works fine
I added field to the entity class type bigDecimal and I can i see while debug the code that the object contain the
values type bigDecimal .
when i read the data from the table i get entries for all the types but not for the bigDecimal(got 0)
any idea what could be the reason for that.
I verify that class contain get and set for the bigDecimal.
BTW I use derby DB with eclipselink

something strange happen which is inconsistent behavior that I debug the process and 
two times i able to see the bigdecimal data ...

This is the entity

```
@Entity
public class emp {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName; 
        private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
```

This is the code to save the data,here object contain the all the values

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(object);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Here is the code that read the data

```
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

String className = classOjc.toString();

            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + className + " p");

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            List resultList = query.getResultList();

            System.out.println(resultList.size());

            for (Object result : resultList) {

                System.out.println(result.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Can you annotate your `bigDecimal` field with `@Column(scale = 2, precision = 10)` (adjust to whatever precision you need)?

Comment: no I cant ,the entity class is coming from exteranl source so I cant change it...

Comment: Too bad. You can try mapping it with `orm.xml` as it overrides annotations, but only as a last resort.

Comment: HI Tomasz ,I dont have orm.xml i have persistence.xml ,can you explain how to do that?

Comment: BTW for testing propose i added the @Column(scale = 2, precision = 10) as you mentiond but it works for the first time (i able to see the value for bigDecimal),when i run the process again the bigDecimal returned =0

Comment: Try turning on EclipseLink logging to see the SQL that gets generated for the table creation and for what gets inserted in the database.  What values are you inserting for your bigDecimal, and what gets returned from a native query on the emp table?